# Best way to define data structure in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not sure that is the best way to define the following use case in firebase database. The app has the following structure.

- STUDIO - Container
- ADMIN - can create, read and update Trainers and Members
- TRAINER - can create, read and update members
- MEMBER - can signup, read and edit own data

Important ADMIN, TRAINER, MEMBER are all users who can login.

Where I should save the relationship form TRAINER to STUDIO, MEMBER to STUDIO and ADMIN to STUDIO.

```
|____firebase
| |____studios
| | |____Studio_A
| | | |____trainers
| | | | |____Trainer_B
| | | | |____Trainer_A
| | | |____Administrator
| | | |____members
| | | | |____Member_B
| | | | |____Member_C
| | | | |____Member_A
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure looks quite good to me. What you'll need to add is something like a `users` node.

Like this:

```
- studios
  - studio-1
    - trainers
      - userid
    - admin
      - userid
    - members
      - userid
- users
  - userid
    - studios
      - studio-1: "member"
    - name // just an example property
    - age // just an example property
```

If a user can have mulitple roles in one studio, you would need to create an array inside the `studios` node.